# Will the FebSmart FS-U4L-Pro PCIE USB 3.0 card work on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, pcie

Does anyone know if the [FebSmart FS-U4L-Pro PCI-e USB 3.0 expansion card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q2BHHRM) will work on Ubuntu 20.04?

At the very bottom it says in somewhat broken English it works with some linux etc. I'm having trouble figuring out how to buy a PCIE USB 3.0 expansion card for linux. I have like 24$ and everything I Google online is not very specific if it works or not. So if this won't work can someone point me in the right direction of where/what to look for?

Comment: PCI-e expansion cards almost never require additional drivers but that doesn't mean you should not research. You ought to contact the manufacturer of the device and ask them

Comment: If the link in the question is broken: [here's why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334767/given-that-stack-exchange-no-longer-adds-its-referral-code-to-rewritten-amazon-l)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does work. I have one myself and I just plug it in and started my computer.
Tested with a USB SSD drive and the speeds are about equal to the internal USB ports. Also camera (Canon) loads fine as well as any USB drive I tested.

Also have a Presonus audiobox Itwo that sits fine in one of the USB ports.

My motherboard are the Gigabyte B550 Gaming X V2 (Ryzen 5600x/32GB)

If the card gives you any problems I would rather think it's becauce of your motherboard than Ubuntu 20.04